# ZSH terminal displaying characters and cursor in the wrong place

Tags: macos, command-line, iterm, zsh

When my command is long and I move the cursor through it, it jumps randomly to different places and start writing in any location of the command.

I'm using OS X El Capitan (10.11.6) and have installed oh my zsh. I've also tested an alternative terminal (iTerm) and the same is happening.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I've just added

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to the file

```
~/.zshrc
```

and solved the issue

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: I've been looking for ages for this solution, thank you!  Why does ZSH not warn me about this or something? I assume this isn't expected behavior?